# what's the popular and recommendatory lightweight java(or python?) web application framework?

Tags: java, python, frameworks, web

I need to develop a lightweight web application, it will:

1. have a simple webgui for administrator to operate;
2. have interface to invoke background existing modules for functionality implement, let's assume it has shell invoke interface firstly, it is not clear yet.

so my question is do we have any popular and  recommendatory lightweight java web application framework? one of my candidate is jboss, do we have the recommendatory jboss version?

we ever done a similar work which use python/flask, i just want to see if any other appropriate java framework.

thanks, 
Emre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/).

If you are not sure, maybe this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5378476/617996) on question "What is pro and contra of using Play Framework?" may help you.

Answer (score 4):

For a lightweight Python web framework it's hard to beat Flask:

http://flask.pocoo.org/

Comment: Not really applicable answer, the parent is asking for a "lightweight java web application framework".

Comment: Actually it says "java(or python?)" if you read it in it's entirety.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [apache stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home).

It is lightweight web application framework on the basis of Java5.0 and COC.

you can fastly develop web applications and u will have less maintenance work.

Answer (score 0):

**Spring MVC 3** is in my experience the

- most flexible
- extensible and
- speedy web framework around

Spring's main purpose was to introduce Dependency Injection for objects.

Another Java lightweight MVC frameworks is **Wicket**.

**Stripes** framework

- Lightweight
- Action based
- Convention over configuration approach
- No XML
- Smart and fun to use
- Much positive feedback (search on SO)

Answer (score 0):

Wonder why Struts has not found place in above list ? Is it too heavy ?